# Running external JS function with document.write asyncronously

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

We have a website that is supposed to be loading a logo provided by a 3rd party (the logo is a link that allows users to see that our site has been verified by that 3rd party.)

To get this to work, we're told to include a short script in the head

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    //<![CDATA[ 
    var tlJsHost = ((window.location.protocol == "https:") ? 
        "https://secure.comodo.com/" : "http://www.trustlogo.com/");
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + tlJsHost + 
        "trustlogo/javascript/trustlogo.js' 
        type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
    //]]>
</script>
```

And another script in the body:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    TrustLogo("https://ourfakesite.com/logo.png", "CL1", "none");
</script>
```

This all worked fine, initially: the external script is loaded, the function is run, the logo shows up.  Perfect.

The problem occurred when the remote site got really slow...all of our pages that load this logo suddenly became very slow as well, since the script is running synchronously.

Ideally, I'd like this to work as if it were designed as an ajax type call...load the page, and after the page is loaded, attempt to load the extra content.

I've tried some combinations of async/defer and using things like ajax, but it seems that because the JS is using a document.write, if the page is fully loaded, the document.write blows away the existing document before writing the new data; the page loads...and then disappears and the logo appears.  (I've seen some commentary explaining that this is expected behavior when document.write is used after the page is loaded.)

Is there a way to do this?  Is there an alternate path I'm not considering?

Comment: Maybe move the script from the head to the bottom of the body. Only, ofcourse if the image is somewhere in or near the footer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at `https://secure.comodo.com/trustlogo/javascript/trustlogo.js`, the `TrustLogo` function itself uses `document.write` (indirectly, the code is minified, but eventually it does), which means you can't use those scripts asynchronously. If you make the first script asynchronous and append that JavaScript file another way, then you have to make the second script asynchronous, and that would mean `document.write` (within the `TrustLogo` function) would be called after the main HTML parsing is complete, which in turn means that there'd be an implicit `document.open`, which would erase your page. :-(

Of course...you could put all of that in an `iframe` on your main page, so that only the `iframe`, not your whole page, is impacted. Provided that's not a violation of the terms of use of the logo (obviously, you'd use a relative path for the `iframe` so their code sees the right domain and such).

Comment: Unfortunate, but this is the conclusion that I was coming to as well (though, since I'm a relative JS tyro, I wasn't ready to give up until I ran it by some people smarter than me.)  The iframe idea is also worth considering...I'll have to check the terms of the logo usage.  Thanks!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, it does use `document.write` according to its code.

Comment: @UtkarshPramodGupta - If so, then [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51846729/157247) won't work, for the reasons I mention above.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, Sir! I understand that. But, it seems like I have found a hack for it and I need you to look into my answer I'm about to post and comment whatever comes to your mind. :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'll look around and see if I can easily find one on a site.  Unfortunately, because of the loading issue I described, it's currently removed from our site, so viewing it there isn't an option right now.

Comment: @Beska - No need, I realized I was being dense, all the information I needed was in your question (I updated the answer a few minutes ago).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder No problem at all...easy to lose a bit of detail in that wall-of-question.  Your assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would love to see how is the code for this to work on an iframe. It would help me a lot but I don't know how to do it. Can you guys help me?